# I'm getting a warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++

My program seems to be working fine in visual studio but when I run it in GCC, its giving me a compilation error called

```
Book.cpp: In member function â€˜sdds::Book& sdds::Book::addChapter(const char*, int)â€™:
Book.cpp:64:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

and I don't know what to do, can someone please help?
This was the function in which I am getting the error in

```
 Book& addChapter(const char* chapter_name, int noOfPages)
    {
        // create a new chapter
        Chapter chapter(chapter_name, noOfPages);
        // check if chapter is valid
        if (chapter.isValidChapter()) {
            // add the chapter to list of chapters
            // create a new list of chapters
            Chapter* chapters = new Chapter[this->noOfChapters + 1];
            // copy chapters to new array
            for (int i = 0; i < this->noOfChapters; i++)
                chapters[i] = this->chapters[i];
            // add the last chapter
            chapters[this->noOfChapters++] = chapter;
            // delete the old list of chapters
            delete this->chapters;
            // update the list of chapters
            this->chapters = chapters;
            return *this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your function says it returns a `Book &` in the signature but you don't return anything in the actual definition. Even after your edit now, it still returns nothing if `!chapter.isValidChapter()`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 what am i supposed to return?

Comment: I assume it's an error if `!chapter.isValidChapter()`, so try to return something that indicates an error. In this case you need to return a reference, so maybe have a known global object that's supposed to indicate an error and return that when there is one?

Comment: what do you mean return something that indiacates an error?

Comment: How do you want to handle a situation where `chapter` is not a valid chapter? (BTW you could also use an exception)

Comment: Does `return *this` just need to be outside the if statement?

Comment: Throwing exception might be a possibility.

Comment: Avoid raw owning pointers, use `std::vector` instead here. (and if you can't use std, write your own simplified vector).

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that the function:
`addChapter`
waits for some return value.
Of course you have one return in the `If statment` but, if the statement is False, the program can crash. Because function has nothing to return, but is expected to return something.

easy fix: **ensure that function always returns some value**